# Code efficiency for text analysis

Tags: php, regex, performance, memory-efficient

I need advice regarding text analysis. 
The program is written in php.

My code needs to receive a URL and match the site words against the DB and seek for a match.

The tricky part is that the words aren't allways written in the DB as they appear in the text.

example:

Let's say my DB has these values:
Word  = letters

And the site has:
Wordy thing

I'm supposed to output:
Letters thing

My code makes several regex an after each one tries to match the searched word against the DB.

For each word that isn't found I make 8 queries to the DB. Most of the words don't have a match so when we talk about a whole website that has hundreds of words my CPU level makes a jump.

I thought about storing every word not found in the DB globaly as they appear ( HD costs less than CPU ) or maybe making an array or dictionary to store all of that.

I'm really confused with this project. It's supposed to serve a lot of users, with the current code the server will die after 10-20 user requests.

Any thoughts?

Edit:
The searched words aren't English words and the code runs in a windows 2008 server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.
Unfortunately none of the answers helped me, maybe I wasn't clear enough.

I ended up solving the issue by creating a hash table with all of the words on the DB (about 6000 words), and checking against the hash instead of the DB.

The code started up with 4 sec execution time and now it's 0.5 sec! :-)

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Implement a trie and compute levenstein distance?  See this blog for a detailed walkthrough of implementation: http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=114

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like a job for [Sphynx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) & [stemming](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.8.html#conf-morphology).

Comment: I'm not sure i can use third party programs.. If I need to do this only with my code, what would be the best approach?

Comment: Licencing for start, and the server isn't dedicated.

Comment: No license needed (GPLv2), not having a dedicated server (or even a dedicated VPS) can indeed become troublesome, especially because we are talking performance, and replacing text in whole websites. You could store all the words/regexes to be translated in some apc- of memcached array, saving you a database trip, but it depends on whether words in the text are likely to be in the database or not.

Comment: If the words to be translated are reasonably limited, you could go for a preg_replace with 2 arrays, like for instance (made up regexes): `preg_replace(array('/word(y|s)/','/box(en|es)/'),array('letter$1','chest$1'),$string));`, but even then, be very cautious about replacing strings in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly stupid question but have you considered using a LIKE clause in your SQL query?
Something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `your_field` LIKE 'your_search'":
```

I've usually found whenever I have to do too much string manipulation on return values from a query I can get it done easier on the SQL side.

Comment: Hm, possibly even more effective: `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 'the_entire_document' LIKE CONCAT('%',your_field,'%');`